# Snowpack - import scss into tsx

Tags: sass, snowpack

I am setting up a Snowpack project with the aim to move an existing Create-React-App application into it once things are configured the same.

I haven't found a way to import an `.scss` file into a `.tsx` file however.

The Snowpack docs only seem to discuss configuring scss as an externally built asset, suggesting putting your scss into a separate `css` folder { [docs link](https://www.snowpack.dev/#sass) }. However I would like to keep my `scss` files next to the `tsx` components they belong to, and import them into the component as I currently am.
The docs also reference [a blog post discussing a setup with PostCSS](https://zellwk.com/blog/eleventy-snowpack-sass-postcss/), however that post suggests some issues with the approach, including that sourcemaps wouldn't work - which isn't going to fly.

I have created my project like this:

```
npx create-snowpack-app my-sweet-app --template @snowpack/app-template-react-typescript --use-yarn
```

I've then added a new scss file, `src/test.scss`

```
$best-colour: tomato;

body {
    background-color: $best-colour;
}
```

and added an import in my `src/App.tsx` file:

```
import './test.scss';
```

When running `yarn start` I get the following error:

```
[error] [404] /_dist_/test.css.proxy.js
    ✘ /home/me/repos/my-sweet-app/public/_dist_/test.css
    ✘ /home/me/repos/my-sweet-app/src/test.css
```

Can Snowpack be configured to import scss files into tsx files equivalent to how it works in Create React App? How?

Comment: Did you setup the `run:sass` scripts in your snowpack config? https://www.snowpack.dev/#sass

Comment: @Valentin the docs you linked seem to take some *.scss files in src/css and compile them to *.css files in public/css. However I'm trying to have my scss files compiled and then bundled as JS within my JS bundle files - replicating the behaviour of webpacks sass loader.

Answer (score 1):

While I have not a complete answer, I faced the same problem as you. What you basically want to achieve is, to add additional tools to Snowpack's build pipeline.

If you throw in [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) [with Snowpack](https://www.snowpack.dev/#babel) you can add arbitrary absurd babel plugins for all your transformation needs.

Using [@researchgate/babel-plugin-transform-scss-import-to-string](https://github.com/researchgate/babel-plugin-transform-scss-import-to-string) and adding it in my `babel.config.js` I was able to get my Sassy stuff transpiled into strings.

However, this is not a complete solution; because now Snowpack won't pick up changes in my Sass files... :( It seem's that a lot of those new *anti bundlers* are just that, they are against bundling and thus combining them with additional pre-processing stuff that *used to be* done by our good olde bundlers is *cumbersome*.

Comment: Thanks, that's a decent workaround! I've since moved from Snowpack to ViteJS, having much more success there!